# Extract GPS meta data of a video using C#

Tags: c#, gps, metadata, exiftool, metadata-extractor

I have tried following libraries in c# (.net core)

1. Media Info
2. Metadata Extractor
3. Tag Lib
4. Media Tool Kit

I wasn't able to retrieve GPS metadata from any of these libraries of a video.
But for an image, it worked fine. Also, I tried the Exif tool, but no luck.

Following are some code samples I used. Looking for help on this.

```
// using metadata extractor
var byteArray = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync("./meta_video.mp4");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

var directories = QuickTimeMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(stream);
var directories1 = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata("./meta_image1.jpg");
            
// using tag lib
var tfile = TagLib.File.Create(@"./meta_video.mp4");
            
// using media tool kit
var inputFile = new MediaToolkit.Model.MediaFile {Filename = @"./meta_video.mp4"};
using (var engine = new Engine())
{
                engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
}

// using media info
string fileNameAndPath = "./video2.mp4";
var myVideo = new MediaFile(fileNameAndPath);
```

Comment: GPS data can come in two forms in a video.  There can be a single coordinate held in the `GPSPosition` tag and there can be GPS track as part of the stream.   Exiftool can extract the first one easily.  A GPS track is more complicated.  If you add the [`-ee` (`-extractEmbedded`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ee--extractEmbedded), then exiftool will be able to extract a track if it knows the format.  The main problem is there isn't a standard for an embedded GPS track.  Exiftool currently knows 59 different ways a track can be embedded.

Comment: I tried these commands. Image and video was taken using my mobile.

"C:\Users\....\exiftool.exe -ee C:\Users\....\meta_video.mp4" -----
"C:\Users\....\exiftool.exe -ee C:\Users\....\meta_img.jpg"

For the image gps record came. But for the video, they are not coming. Any idea?

Comment: Are you certain that the video contains GPS data?  If so, I'd suggest posting a sample over on the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum) where the author of exiftool take a look and see if he can add support for it.

Comment: Oh. Looks like my fault. Video seems not having gps meta data. Metadata extractor plugin works fine for images. Any place where I can find a video sample.

Comment: There are some on the exiftool forums.  For example, [this thread](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=5095.0) has multiple examples scattered through out the whole thing.